# How to get the new ISO (from source code?)?

Tags: system-installation, updates

6.0-rc1 was just released. I couldn't find the iso there, only 2 assets (2 files in archive formats). How to create an ISO (if that's the assets are for)?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't actually a 6.0-rc1 available. Beta 1 and Beta 2 have been on https://builds.elementary.io/ for a while, but those are .iso files. Where are you downloading from?

Comment: No, I mean 6.0-rc1 was on GitHub. Check the "os" section here: https://releases.elementary.io/ or here: https://github.com/elementary/os/releases/tag/6.0-rc1

Comment: Yep, that's the build system generating a release. They are now on https://builds.elementary.io/ and you will need to be a sponsor of elementary on GitHub to access them.

Comment: Thank you. And do you know if the final release of Odin also going to be only for the sponsors, or at first sponsors-only then after some time, general public?

Comment: The official stable release will be made available pretty much as the current stable release is now on the main site.

Answer (score 1):

ISO's are available pre-built by sponsoring elementary on GitHub and can be downloaded at https://builds.elementary.io/

---

If you wish to build you own ISO, the instructions are avilable in the repository wiki at https://github.com/elementary/os/wiki/Building-ISO-Images

Comment: Thank you, Lewis.